# Installing a dependency in PyCharm conda environment using PyCharm terminal

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, dependencies, conda

I have created a conda env using `conda create env` command in PyCharm. After running `conda activate <env_name>`, I can also see the name of the environment in my shell before username in parenthesis. But when I run `pip3 install xxx`, it doesn't install in that environment. So, I have to go to PyCharm Preference and add that dependency using their user interface and then it works.

Wanted to know what mistake am I making that even when the environment is activated in PyCharm terminal, the dependency isn't installing in that environment.

Comment: Why did you not use Conda instead of pip?

Comment: Should it not work with pip? @ANUJSINGH If yes, I wanted to know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Default way of installing packages to conda environments is described here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages

TLDR: `conda install xxx`